# Getting attribute error and key error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am running

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv("RELIANCE.csv",parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
df.head(2)
```

It gives output below

```
                    Open    High        Low          Close  Adj Close Volume
Date                        
2019-08-19  1281.050049 1296.800049 1280.000000 1292.599976 1287.764648 7459859.0
2019-08-20  1289.800049 1292.599976 1272.599976 1275.949951 1271.176880 6843460.0
```

but `type(df.Date[0])` throws `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'` and `df['2019-08-19']` throws `KeyError: '2019-08-19'`

Can anybody tell me How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc['2019-08-19']
```

---

`AttributeError` is probably because index name is not stored as a attribute for any data frame, so you can't address it directly. Instead, you can do something like `type(df.index[0])` or `df.index.dtype` to index type.